# If someone was murdered was this Allahs plan

Tags: murder

My son was killed in a home invasion, was this Allahs death date for him or was it interrupted by the killers. I need help understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happens in this world, happens by the permission of Allah. But doesn't mean Allah is making people do all bad thing that is happening in the world. Whatever way a man or anyone or anything can behave is determined by Allah. So a man can have number of good ways and number of bad ways allowed by Allah for him. So a man who is god conscious should from the good ways.

About your son's death, it happened because Allah allowed it happen. May be Allah will forgive your son's sins and admit him into paradise as he was wrongly killed. Once an event happen, it is Allah's death date for him. Also sometimes if Allah already decide someone die on particular place or date, that would definitely happen. So your son's death was one particular way that Allah allowed and it happened because the person who did it decided to go on the wrong path allowed by Allah. So he will have sin for doing that, may be Allah forgive him later on that is different issue.

Comment: Quote:- "Whatever happens in this world, happens by the permission of Allah........"; "...he was wrongly killed" May I ask, how could a killing done "by the permission of Allah", be "wrongly done"?

Comment: Allah allows good and bad things to happen, it is not that Allah do not have powers to stop the bad things, he just allow them to happen. If Allah only allowed good things in the world, no body will be able to sin and there will be no free will. Everybody will be forced to do good things only.  So what I meant by "wrongly" is that, it can be a sin in the sight of Allah but still he allowed it.

Comment: Quote:- "So what I meant by "wrongly" is that, it can be a sin in the sight of Allah but still he allowed it" You are wrong. Allah does not "allow" sin or sinning by anyone. Allah only forgives sin after repentance. If Allah allows sin or sinning, then there is no need for repentance of something which He has already allowed?

Comment: Allowed is not in the sense that it is lawful or halal, I meant to say Allah didn't want to stop the sin. That is reason, people can sin in this world.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please accept my condolences for your sad loss and grief. It must be a terrible time for you and your family.

As for your question, the answer has to be a "yes", (there is no other credible answer), i.e. it was definitely part of Allah's plan, and no one, not even home invasion murderers could change it or, as you put it, "interrupted"

If any human could change or interrupt Allah's plans, then Allah would not be Allah anymore, isn't it?

Millions of incidences, good or bad, happen every second somewhere on Earth, and if every "bad" incidence is an "interruption" of Allah's plans, then Allah's plans are being interrupted millions of time every second?

As for the question, what then is Allah's post-death "plan" is a matter for pure speculation, as no human is privy to Allah's plan, not even @Shafeek.

Of course we all hope that Allah will have mercy upon your son's soul and admit him into Paradise.

Comment: No body know what is post-death plan, that is why I added "May be" to "Allah will forgive".

Comment: Quote:- ""May be" to "Allah will forgive" "Maybe" means to speculate. Please read up on what the Quran says about "speculation"?

Comment: Speculating because we can't be sure what Allah wills. Nobody can know what Allah will decide. So we always hope for the best from Allah but finally it is Allah to decide.

Comment: Allah says: "What comes to you of good is from Allah , but what comes to you of evil, [O man], is from yourself. And We have sent you, [O Muhammad], to the people as a messenger, and sufficient is Allah as Witness." ([4:79](https://legacy.quran.com/4/79)) and He says:"Say, "O mankind, the truth has come to you from your Lord, so whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul, and whoever goes astray only goes astray [in violation] against it. And I am not over you a manager.""([10:108](https://legacy.quran.com/10/108)) where or how is this addressed in your answer?

Comment: Allah showed humans right and wrong so they are able to decide and therefore they are responsible and accountable for their deeds.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Quote:- "My son was killed in a home invasion, was this Allahs death date for him or was it interrupted by the killers" This was OP's question. Please give a full answer to this question so that OP will understand and be guided?

Comment: Well its you who posted an answer, as you may think you are able to answer, but to me this answer sounds anything but "full". That's why I've commented it, hoping you can address these inputs adequately.

Comment: Salam, thank you so much for your response, i appreciate it with all my heart. I'm trying so hard to learn more about our religion and I just need to finally fully believe, like everything you said that sounds so accurate inshallah that can come to me soon to wrap my head around it. I just keep beating myself up saying if this or if that then maybe he wouldn't have been brutally murdered.  thank you again 